# Synchronization error occurs while running my program

Tags: mysql, jpa, jsf-2, glassfish, primefaces

I am using JSF2.0/primefaces , MySql, Glassfish3.1 .

I have three tables: person, file, domaineCompetence

person(name,......,idDomaineCompetence)

file(idFile,nameFile,......,idPerson)

domaineCompetence(idDomaineCompetence.....)

When a person is added to the database in the same time a row will be added
into the file table.

But an error occurs after submitting. Actually I have two errors. I dont know why but one of them (not both in the same time) appear after I execute the program.

the index.xhtml:

```
<h:form>

    <p:panel header="Add User"    style="width: 500px; font-size: 14px">
       <h:panelGrid width="width: 300px;"    columns="2">


          <h:outputLabel style="font-size: 13px" value="Nom" /> <h:inputText value="#{AddPerson.nom}" />
          <h:outputLabel value="Prenom"/> <h:inputText value="#{AddPerson.prenom}" />
          <h:outputLabel value="Etat Civil"/>
          <h:selectOneMenu id="etatcivil" value="#{AddPerson.etatCivil}">
              <f:selectItem itemValue="Monsieur" itemLabel="M"/>
              <f:selectItem itemValue="Madam" itemLabel="Mme"/>
              <f:selectItem itemValue="Madmoiselle" itemLabel="Mlle"/>
           </h:selectOneMenu>

           <h:outputLabel value="Date de naissance "/> 
            <p:calendar value="#{AddPerson.dateNaissance}" id="popupButtonCal" showOn="button" />
             <h:outputLabel value="email"/><h:inputText value="#{AddPerson.email}" />
             <h:outputLabel value="numTelephone"/><h:inputText value="#{AddPerson.numTelephone}" />
             <h:outputLabel value="mobile"/><h:inputText value="#{AddPerson.mobile}" />
             <h:outputLabel value="fax"/><h:inputText value="#{AddPerson.fax}" />
             <h:outputLabel value="profession"/><h:inputText value="#{AddPerson.profession}" />
             <h:outputLabel value="adresse"/><h:inputText value="#{AddPerson.adresse}" />
             <h:outputLabel value="code Postal"/><h:inputText value="#{AddPerson.codePostal}" />
             <h:outputLabel value="Ville"/><h:inputText value="#{AddPerson.ville}" />
              <h:outputLabel value="Pays"/><h:inputText value="#{AddPerson.pays}" />


              <h:outputLabel value="Domaine de Competence"/>
                 <h:selectOneMenu  value="#{AddPerson.domain}" id="domaine" >
                  <f:selectItem itemLabel="-- Select Domaine de Competence-- " itemValue="0"/> 
                  <f:selectItems value="#{AddPerson.listDomaine}" />
                 </h:selectOneMenu>


               <h:outputLabel value="login"/><h:inputText value="#{AddPerson.login}" />
               <h:outputLabel value="password"/><h:inputText value="#{AddPerson.password}" />
               <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{AddPerson.fileUpload}"   update="messages"   sizeLimit="500000"    allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/"/>  
               <h:commandButton action="#{AddPerson.addUserDB}"  value="Add User" />      
         </h:panelGrid>
     </p:panel>
 </h:form>
```

Bean AddPerson.java:

```
public class AddPerson implements Serializable{





   EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("testPU");
   EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();


   private String nom;
   private String prenom;
   private Date dateNaissance;
   private String lieuNaissance;
   private String etatCivil;
   private String email;
   private int  numTelephone;
   private int  mobile;
   private int fax;
   private String profession;
   private String login;
   private String  password;
   private String adresse;
   private int codePostal;
   private String ville;
   private String pays;
   private FileUploadEvent event;
   private File file;
   private static List<SelectItem> listDomaine;
   private String domain;  

  //getters and setters



   public void fileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) throws IOException {
     String path = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRealPath("/");
     SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
     String name = fmt.format(new Date())+ event.getFile().getFileName().substring(event.getFile().getFileName().lastIndexOf('.'));
     file = new File("C:/Users/Documents/NetBeansProjects/test/uploaded files/" + name);

     InputStream is = event.getFile().getInputstream();
     OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);


      byte buf[] = new byte[1024];
      int len;
       while ((len = is.read(buf)) > 0)
         out.write(buf, 0, len);

      is.close();
      out.close();

   }



  public List<SelectItem> getListDomaine() {
     FindDomaine fdom= new FindDomaine();

     if (listDomaine == null) {
        listDomaine = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
        for (String val : fdom.FindAllDomaine()) {
            listDomaine.add(new SelectItem(val));
        }
    }
    return listDomaine;
  }




  public void addUserDB() {
      try {

        EntityTransaction entr = em.getTransaction();
        entr.begin();

        Personne user = new Personne();
        Fileuploaded fileup =new Fileuploaded();
        Domainecompetence dom=new Domainecompetence();
        user.setNom(nom);
        user.setPrenom(prenom);
        user.setCodepostal(codePostal);
        user.setEmail(email);
        user.setEtatCivil(etatCivil);
        user.setFax(fax);
        user.setLieuNaissance(lieuNaissance);
        user.setDateNaissance(dateNaissance);
        user.setMobile(mobile);
        user.setAdresse(adresse);
        user.setPays(pays);
        user.setLogin(login);
        user.setPassword(password);
        user.setPassword(password);
        fileup.setFileName(file.getName());
        fileup.setFilePath(file.getPath());
        fileup.setIdPersonne(user);//add the forign key to the table fileupload
        user.setDomaine(dom);

      System.out.println("+++++Test+++++"+this.nom);
      System.out.println("++++++Test++++"+this.prenom);
      System.out.println("++++++Test++++"+this.domain);


        em.persist(user);
        em.persist(fileup);
        entr.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        System.out.println("Failed");
    } finally {
        em.close();
    }

   }

}
```

persistance.xml

```
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
 <persistence-unit name="testPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
 <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
 <class>DTO.Domainecompetence</class>
 <class>DTO.Personne</class>
 <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
 <validation-mode>NONE</validation-mode>
 <properties>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
 </properties>
 </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Error1:

```
Infos: Initialisation de Mojarra 2.1.3 (FCS b02) pour le contexte «/test»
Infos: Instantiated an instance of org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.
Infos: Monitoring jndi:/server/test/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml for modifications
Infos: WEB0671: Loading application [test] at [/test]
Infos: test a été déployé en 3 485 ms.
Infos: file datejava.text.SimpleDateFormat@5069d960
Infos: file name :20120308103902.gif
Infos: ++++++++++julie
Infos: ++++++++++julie
Infos: ++++++++++Securite informatique
Infos: Object: DTO.Personne[ idPersonne=null ] is not a known entity type.
Infos: Failed
```

Error 2:

```
Infos: file datejava.text.SimpleDateFormat@5069d960
Infos: file name :20120308102712.gif
Infos: Base de donnee
Infos: ++++++++++julie
Infos: ++++++++++julie
Infos: ++++++++++Base de donnee
Infos: [EL Warning]: 2012-03-08 10:27:15.604--UnitOfWork(5810583)--java.lang.IllegalStateException: During synchronization a new object was found through a relationship that was not marked cascade PERSIST: DTO.Domainecompetence[ domaine=null ].

Infos: java.lang.IllegalStateException: During synchronization a new object was found through a relationship that was not marked cascade PERSIST: DTO.Domainecompetence[ domaine=null ].
Infos: Failed
Infos: PWC2785: Cannot serialize session attribute AddPerson for session 1a185521c447acaa561b45f616d7
```

personne.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "personne", catalog = "test", schema = "", uniqueConstraints = {
@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"idPersonne"})})
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name = "Personne.findAll", query = "SELECT p FROM Personne p"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Personne.findByIdPersonne", query = "SELECT p FROM Personne p   WHERE p.idPersonne = :idPersonne"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Personne.findByNom", query = "SELECT p FROM Personne p WHERE p.nom = :nom"),
 @JoinColumn(name = "domaine", referencedColumnName = "domaine")
 @ManyToOne
 private Domainecompetence domaine;
```

Update:

domaineCompetence.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "domainecompetence", catalog = "test", schema = "")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name = "Domainecompetence.findAll", query = "SELECT d FROM Domainecompetence d"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Domainecompetence.findByDomaine", query = "SELECT d FROM Domainecompetence d WHERE d.domaine = :domaine")})
public class Domainecompetence implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 200)
@Column(name = "domaine", nullable = false, length = 200)
private String domaine;
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, mappedBy = "domaine") //and I have tried CascadType.ALL
private Collection<Personne> personneCollection;
//getters and setters
```

}

Comment: Do you have entity classes? Or more concrete: Is your Personne class annotated with @Entity annotation?

Comment: @Matt Handy yes it did , I will update my question

Comment: Maybe your entity relations are not set correctly. Did you create the entity classes yourself or automatically with the help of the IDE?

Comment: I have created the entity classes automatically

Comment: Updated my answer, according to your update.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the second error:

You try to persist an entity (`Personne`) that has another entity (`DomainCompetence`) attached through a relation in your entity class. However you did not set this relation as `CASCADE=PERSIST` or `CASCADE=ALL`. So the EntityManager doesn't know what to do with this entity. Here is an example how the cascade attribute can be set:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "...")
private List<Personne> personneList;
```

Look into your `DomainCompetence` entity class and change it accordingly. Hope this helps a bit further.